# Error when testing gpload based on windows

Tags: python, greenplum, hawq

When i try to execute gpload from Windows based ETL host.

Using gpload in a Windows environment produces the following error:

**Error I Get:**

> gpload.py -f gpload.yml

```
gpload was unable to import The PyGreSQL Python module (pg.py) - DLL load failed with error code 193
```

Comment: Try installing the 32 bit version of Python 2.5 rather than the 64 bit version.

Comment: Thanks Jon.  I Installed it and it is working for me.  Getting  this error code   now -http response code 404 from gpfdist

Comment: try running gpfdist.exe directly and see if you are able to start the process.  It might be a simple port conflict or anti-virus stopping the process.

Comment: Yes, I started the gpfdist process at ETL server and getting this as Output console . https://paste.ofcode.org/K3jCbiWRLY9PJGpSt9hXfP

Comment: So you now should stop the gpfdist.exe process, edit your yml file, and make sure you are using port 8080.  Also, make sure the hostname you are using is the Windows hostname and it resolves correctly.  Lastly, you will need to make sure all of the segment hosts can resolve that name.  All of the segments will be connecting to the host you specify and port 8080.

Comment: Ok Jon I will  conduct above mentioned  in my env.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/137068/discussion-between-sylphes-and-jon-roberts).

Answer (score 1):

You should check whether your pygresql installed correctly or not. Because from the gpload code

```
try:
    from pygresql import pg
except Exception, e:
    errorMsg = "gpload was unable to import The PyGreSQL Python module (pg.py) - %s\n" % str(e)
    sys.stderr.write(str(errorMsg))
    sys.exit(2)
```

we can know that this is an error about import pygresql (installed or not, version is right ?). If pygresql installed correctly, whether python version or PATH is right ? Please check them.

Comment: This error resolve. However,gpload insert is not working from  Windows.

Comment: When i am trying to execute from windows command prompt . gpload is working fine. But when trying to Automate the process using  tgreenplumGPload  not working .